# Full outer join from rows of one table based on values from another table

Tags: mysql, oracle, teradata

I have these 2 tables:

```
CONTS
ID      SRC_ID      VAL
----    ------      ---
1000    100           2
1000    100           4
1000    100           8

1000    101           2
1000    101           0
1000    101           8

1000    102           2
1000    102           4
1000    102           8

1000    103           3
1000    103           5
1000    103           8

1001    110          12
1001    110           5

1001    111          12

and VALID:
ID      SRC_ID  VALID_ID
----    ------  --------
1000    101          102
1001    110          111
```

I need an SQL query that joins 2 tables with millions of rows. There are 2 tables `CONTS` and `VALID`. In table `VALID`, column `ID` is primary key (there is only one row per unique ID).

I need to get this result:

```
ID    SRC_ID1  VAL1  SRC_ID2  VAL2
----  -------  ----  -------  ----
1000      101     2      102     2
1000     NULL  NULL      102     4
1000      101     0     NULL  NULL
1000      101     8      102     8

1001      110    12      111    12
1001      110     5     NULL  NULL
```

The SQL should work in Teradata or Oracle.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you use Mysql, Oracle?? What have you tried (if you have tried something) ? Where do you get VAL1 and VAL2 from? What´s the relation between CONTS and VALID?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: The relations between table CONTS and VALID are:
CONTS.ID - VALID.ID (1..N - 1), 
 
CONTS.SRC_ID - VALID.SRC_ID (1..N - 1), 
  
CONTS.SRC_ID - VALID.SRC_ID (1..N - 1)
  
CONTS.SRC_ID - VALID.VALID_ID
   0,1..N - 0,1

Answer (score 0):

I almost got it, but don't know if this is the optimal solution from a performance point of view:

`SELECT COALESCE(T1.ID, T2.ID) AS ID, T1.SRC_ID, T1.VAL, T2.SRC_ID AS SRC_ID, T2.VAL
FROM (
    SELECT v.ID, v.SRC_ID, c1.VAL
    FROM VALID v
    LEFT JOIN CONTS c1 ON (c1.ID = v.ID and c1.SRC_ID = v.SRC_ID)
) T1
FULL OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT v.ID, v.VALID_ID AS SRC_ID, c1.VAL
    FROM VALID v
    LEFT JOIN CONTS c1 ON (c1.ID = v.ID and c1.SRC_ID = v.VALID_ID)
) T2 ON (T2.ID = T1.ID and T2.VAL = T1.VAL)`

Comment: As long as there are no duplicate VALs per SRC_ID this might be what you want, you just need to add COALESCE on the SRC_IDs, too. Performance is probably the best you can get with your strange datamodel :-)